# There are 3 things not made of matter

Tags: definition, matter, states-of-matter

When I'm teaching middle school science and I'm teaching the concept of matter I usually tell them that everything is made of matter except for 3 things.

Space-Time, Energy (light, heat, kinetic, potential, etc) and Abstractions (happiness, love, running, numbers, etc)

Although Space-Time is not on the syllabus the students love to hear anything that follow ''this is not on the syllabus but ...''

Is this a fair statement or am I leaving something out?

Comment: Hmm ... that never even occurred to me. But after thinking about it I think it is matter. I mean anti-matter particles have mass.

Comment: What does it mean exactly? One could argue that energy is an abstraction, or that happiness is made of matter (as a state of the brain).
I don't think this question actually has a physics content, it's about general education, language or philosophy.

Comment: I recommend sticking with examples of what *is* made of matter: our bodies; the air; planets and stars, etc. And contrasting this with vacuum, such as outer space.

Comment: Making examples without defining what you mean by matter is meaningless.

Comment: If you say that light is not matter, do you say anything about how do we know it?

Comment: @GiorgioP You are right and I agree with you. That's why I do define matter in my class. Yes, I do say something about why we say that light is not matter. I'm not going to post my entire class here.

Comment: Well, if you do not explain how you define matter, it is impossible to say if you are leaving something out. Of course, you can omit the rest of your class :-)

Comment: @GiorgioP Ok well the standard one sentence definition for matter in secondary school is ''that which has mass and takes up space''.

Comment: With this definition, you are left with abstractions only, since taking space is not applicable to space-time and a box with light inside does have energy  ( $E=mc^2$). Energy in turn is a property of a physical system, it is not itself a physical system. In any case your students cannot check experimentally your claims about the mass, so you are asking them to trust you, instead of explaining them "how do we know that...".

Answer (score 1):

It is fair for the middle school level. Mass-energy equivalence and the complications of space-time would make your lesson a bit more confusing so your statement should be good.

Answer (score 1):

Please note that light is not a form of energy, rather it carries energy, just as matter does. In my opinion, the most clear and unambiguous example of "stuff" that is not matter is in fact light. One might regard spacetime also as a "stuff", a physical entity, but that is a bit more muddled in how you define "physical" and which model you are using. Personally I'd regard the contents of the universe as matter and  light, which have energy, and exist in spacetime. "Abstractions" are just one of many /emergent properties/ that result from this fundamental system.